# QGIS 2.18: Filter line-layer by QgsExpression

Tags: qgis, filter, expression, ppygis, qgsfeaturerequest

I have a line layer on which I want to run a filter within a python script.
I am trying to achieve this via QgsExpression and QgsFeatureRequest.

Below you see the same filter that I want to apply in the python script as well:
[image]

In my python script i have an id to search for. But before I can filter by id, I have to cut the From and To string from the id so that I get all id with the specified number. Then I apply a request which you see in the code snippet below. But I get no results. I am not entering the for loop which loops through the results:

```
# trim edgeid (cut From and To)
edgeid_trimmed = edgeid_out.replace('From','')
edgeid_trimmed = edgeid_trimmed.replace('To','')

# get azimuth of edge (graph)
filter_edgeid_exp = QgsExpression('\"id\" LIKE \" ' + edgeid_trimmed + '%\" ')
request2= QgsFeatureRequest(filter_edgeid_exp)
request2.setLimit(2)

for j,feat2 in inputGraph.getFeatures(request2):
    print "found edges with requested edgeid"
    if j == 0:
        edge1_id = feat2.attributes()[idx_edgeid]
    else:
        edge2_id = feat2.attributes()[idx_edgeid]
```

However, I do not believe the expression in the QgsExpression(...) is wrong. So what else could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS expressions, double quote are for fields, simple quotes are for strings.

In your case, I think you might replace by :

```
filter_edgeid_exp = QgsExpression('"id" LIKE \'' + edgeid_trimmed + '%\'')
```

Comment: tried that already, but does not work either.

Comment: Could you add a `print(filter_edgeid_exp)` after setting *filter_edgeid_exp*, and give the resulting string ?

Comment: if I print the expression in your way (print(filter_edgeid_exp)), I get this: <qgis._core.QgsExpression object at 0x0000000047C9CF28>

Comment: okay, got it. I missed one space... thank you so much!